# How to keep same header/footer across pages in jQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, layout, footer

Is there an easy method to keep the same header/footer while navigating jQueryMobile pages? The only solutions I came across so far relies on injecting it dynamicly on page-change, but this screws up the transitions, and just clones the elements, I need the original.

So is there an officially supported way? I find it strange that I seem the only one struggling with this problem?

Comment: You mean have them fixed during transition without animation? Or have the same header/ footer for all pages?

Comment: @Omar The same header/footer for all pages.. I would like them to be animated, but its not a big problem if only the page itself is animated.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way is to add a "data-id" attribute to the headers and footers on all pages. To make the header/footer "persistent", use the same data-id across all pages.

```
<div id="page1">
 <div data-role="header" data-id="main-header"></div>
 ...
 <div data-role="footer" data-id="main-footer"></div>
</div>

<div id="page2">
 <div data-role="header" data-id="main-header"></div>
 ...
 <div data-role="footer" data-id="main-footer"></div>
</div>
```

You'd also want to fix the headers and footers either with css or data-position="fixed".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that did it for me! So easy compared to other solutions.

Comment: FYI, This worked for footer but not for header. I tested this in jQM 1.4

Comment: @Mahendra can you tell me, how you implemented this? How do you bind footer to the `<div data-role="footer"></div>`? Do you have a separate `footer.html`?

Comment: @adiga Nope, I didn't separate that out, but used the same footer code across `page`

Comment: It seems this only works if all the pages are in the same file?  (at least for me so far)??

Answer (score 9):

A built in solution for your problem doesn't exist. jQuery Mobile doesn't have a solution that will share a header and footer among loaded pages.

The only thing you can do is dynamical inject them or have them from the beginning. In your case you are doing it at the wrong time. If you want to correctly add a header and footer you need to do it during the correct page event.

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/xwrqn/

Swipe to change pages and see how it works (I didn't want to bother with adding buttons on every page).

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#article2, #article3', function(){ 
    $('<div>').attr({'data-role':'header','data-theme':'b','data-position':'fixed','data-id':'footer'}).append('<h3>Article</h3>').appendTo($(this));
    $('<div>').attr({'data-role':'footer','data-theme':'b','data-position':'fixed','data-id':'footer'}).append('<h3>Article footer</h3>').appendTo($(this));    
});
```

If you do it during the pagebeforecreate this will trigger ONLY once when page is created for a first time. Dynamic content will be added and because pagebeforecreate is triggered before content markup is enhanced you will not need to worry about header and footer styling.

Notice a attribute 'data-id':'footer' added to every header and footer, because of it only content will animate during the page transition, header and footer will look the same. Also, jsFiddle has a bug, when you swipe through pages they will jump 1-2px. This will not happen in a real life example.

Comment: This seems just the kind of solution I wanted to avoid.. For example, if I place a dropdown-box in my footer, and the users makes a selection there, his selection will be lost when just inserting a cloned footer on the next page.

Comment: You are correct, but a good solution don't exist here. You will need to store such data between transitions and show them again in a new page. What ever you think of it this is not that hard of complicated solution. Believe me you will lose more time searching for a solution you want then it will take you to do it like this. Currently in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 page widgets can not be used outside of a apage. It will be possible in jQuery Mobile 1.4 but you will need to wait for it to come out. And event them it is questionable if this will work as intended.

Comment: For now I stopped using the page-system, and just use one page, where I simulate other pages by hiding/showing DIVs. Its really crazy I have to re-invent the wheel, just because the normal paging system doesnt support this. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Gajotres You rule! Out of a 100 answers on how to do this, yours is the only one that works for me! Thanx a lot!

Comment: That's crazy. I have a really big header. And I need to append it by js? I'll search for jquery mobile alternative better...

Comment: My advice, find an alternative to jQuery Mobile, remember we are talking about very old framework here. Also do not forget, my answer was written for jQuery Mobile 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved a similar issue:

```
        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").on("pagecontainerbeforetransition", function (event, ui) {
            $("#header").prependTo(ui.toPage);
            $("#control-panel").appendTo(ui.toPage);
        });
```

Keeps the same header/footer while navigating jQueryMobile pages. Injects it dynamicly on page-change, screws up the transitions, but doesn't clone the elements, gives the original.

Comment: This will add the header/footer before EVERY transition to the page

Comment: It doesn't add.  It moves.  And yes, before every transition.  It's a simple way to address most of the OPs criteria.